# How to prevent Buzzer circuit to drain battery

Tags: low-battery

[image: Simplified circuit]

This circuit drains my battery way too fast.

What can I change to minimize the power consumption?

The Buzzer is a electromechanical variant with these specs:

- Rated Voltage:3V;
- Operating Voltage:2VDC~5VDC;
- Frequency:400±100Hz;
- Rated Current:≤25mA;

Comment: Who knows what the buzzer pulls when you supply it with 9V? Why do you want two LEDs? Why do you want to use a 9V supply?

Comment: Maybe switch to 2x AA batteries (= 3V, nominal)? For more headroom and still within spec, 3x AA batteries (=4.5V, nominal).

Comment: This circuit is simplified and I do not want to draw the complete circuit. The load when the buzzer sounds only consists of the two LEDs and the Buzzer. The 9V battery is needed to operate a Solenoid actuator that is activated later.

Comment: A better design would choose piezo buzzer which is >>1KOhm equivalent rather than magnetic buzzer >100 Ohms which drains battery, then use a 3.0 Lithium button cell to drive buzzer and LEDs and will last as long as 9V alkaline and be much smaller then choose 10Cd LEDs so you can see them easily with 1mA

Comment: @TonyStewart I chose the magnetic buzzer in favor to the piezo buzzer because I need the sound to be a harsh low pitched tone like a game show buzzer "baaah". The Piezo buzzers that I have tried all sounds like high pitched "beep" and it will not have the same effect on the target group. If there are any Piezo buzzers with a low frequent, harsh sounding tone I will surely replace the magnetic with a piezo.

Comment: then you may need a bigger battery such as LiPo cells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have connected a 3 V buzzer to a 9 V battery. Voltage is three times too high. This is likely to cause three times the correct current to flow. Since power is V x I (volts x amps) this will cause 9 x rated power to be dissipated in the buzzer.

You need to add series resistance in circuit with the buzzer to bring the voltage down to 3 V. This means the resistance needs to have 6 V across it so from Ohm's law:

$$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {6}{0.025} = 240~ \Omega $$.

220 Ω is the nearest standard value and will be fine.

Your LED resistors are marked as 10 kΩ. Using Ohm's law we can calculate that the maximum current they can provide is

$$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {9}{10k} = 0.9~mA $$

Most LEDs need about 5 - 20 mA to give a good daylight brightness level. You have enough information to calculate the correct resistance values.

---

You can further improve the efficiency of the LEDs by connecting them in series as the "one current" will drive the two LEDs. They will drop about 2 V each leaving 5 V across the resistor.

You can improve the efficiency AND have bright LEDs!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM4rwM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LEDs can handle 25 mA (check the datasheet) so connect the lot in series and you want 7 V or so at the top of L1 which means R1 needs to drop 2 V at 25 mA. You can work that out?

Comment: Thanks alot @Transistor ! A really educational answer! I suspected that this was the solution and You confirmed it! The choice of 10k was by design to lower the brightness of the LEDs.

Comment: We can do better. See the update.

Comment: Thanks @Transistor for the informative update! My circuit diagram above is a simplified version to describe what components are involved in the battery drain. The LEDs and the buzzer are not activated at the same time and cannot be connected in series. Great idea though.